# Does XAMPP include PHP?

Tags: php, xampp

I have XAMPP installed on my computer as a localhost and I am wondering if I need to install PHP separately? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: XAMPP is an easy to install Apache distribution containing MariaDB, PHP and Perl.

Comment: Yes it does. Even in its name it assures you it does. `XAMPP stands for Cross-Platform (X), Apache (A), MariaDB (M), PHP (P) and Perl (P)`

Comment: What did you think XAMPP was? Did something happen that made you think PHP wasn't included with it?

Comment: I recently installed it on Linux, this is a valid question. The interface doesn't show or list PHP at all - while PHP does appear to be running it is far from obvious that it is actually a part of it in any way aside from the acronym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From XAMPP home page:

> What is XAMPP?
>   XAMPP is a completely free, easy to install Apache distribution
>   containing MariaDB, PHP, and Perl. The XAMPP open source package has
>   been set up to be incredibly easy to install and to use.XAMPP is the most popular PHP development environment

XAMPP comes with PHP already bundled. You don't need a separate PHP installation

Comment: You don't even have to go as far as the home page, in fact. Just Google xampp, and under the first result it says _"XAMPP is an easy to install Apache distribution containing MariaDB, PHP and Perl."_